# contact form 7 wordpress - get user data

Tags: php, wordpress, contacts, contact-form

Does anybody know if its possible to get user data (browser type, operating system) in WordPress plugin - contact form 7?

I am trying to receive this information when ever the user sends an email.

Thanks,
Orly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `[_user_agent]` special mail tag.

For more information, check [this page](http://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/), which lists all available mail tags.